# SAML Logout fails: Issuer does not match (NodeJS + Okta)

Tags: node.js, saml, saml-2.0, okta

I am trying to do a logout with SAML with Okta as my IdP. I am getting "Issuer does not match" in Okta logs:

[image]

I have already setup single logout:

[image]

With the cert uploaded being my SP public key.

---

Code wise:

```
const config = require('../../app/config')
const saml = require('saml2-js')

module.exports = {
  sp: new saml.ServiceProvider({
    entity_id: `${config.HOSTNAME}/saml/assert`,
    private_key: config.SAML_SP_PRIVATE_KEY,
    certificate: config.SAML_SP_PUBLIC_KEY,
    assert_endpoint: `${config.HOSTNAME}/saml/assert`,
    allow_unencrypted_assertion: true,
    sign_get_request: true
  }),

  idp: new saml.IdentityProvider({
    sso_login_url: config.SAML_SSO_LOGIN_URL,
    sso_logout_url: config.SAML_SSO_LOGOUT_URL,
    certificates: config.SAML_SSO_IDP_CERT,
    sign_get_request: true
  })
}
```

And the logout function:

```
if (!req.signedCookies.token) {
  res.status(400).send('Missing token')
  return
}
const tokenData = await jwtVerify(req.signedCookies.token, config.AUTH_SECRET)
const options = {
  name_id: tokenData.name_id,
  session_id: tokenData.session_id,
  sign_get_request: true
}

const createLogoutRequestUrl = util.promisify(sp.create_logout_request_url).bind(sp)
const logoutUrl = await createLogoutRequestUrl(idp, options)
res.redirect(logoutUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK found my mistakes:

My SP entity_id should be the metadata URL

```
entity_id: `${config.HOSTNAME}/saml/metadata`,
```

The config should be reflected in okta too:

[image]